# Which types of animals would peel bark off this tree?

Tags: animals, animal-behaviour, animal-identification, trees

I'm just curious which animals would peel bark off a tree like this:

[image]

It's a riparian setting in the Mid Atlantic region. I was thinking maybe a beaver?

Comment: Hi amphibient. Would you mind explaining what a riparian setting is? I'm not a hiker so I don't know the terminology. It's a cool word though! Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/riparian

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That was definitely a beaver. Nothing else has quite the chewing power of a beaver, for example accoring to Wikipedia, these trees were cut by beavers in a single night.

[image]

Based on the color of those chips, I would say that you were there less than a week if not sooner from when the beaver was chewing the tree down.

The reason that I don't think its a porcupine, is because of the riparian setting and because porcupines usually chew much higher up on a tree.

Fun fact, beaver's teeth [never stop growing](http://www.beaversolutions.com/beaver-facts-biology-behavior/).

Comment: And probably a young beaver.  Notice the difference between the question and answer photos.  The question photo, is not the work of an experienced worker who getting the job done.  More like a teenager experimenting with a new discovery.

Comment: @JamesJenkins: Do you have a source for the behaviour differences of young beavers? I'd be interested to read up on that. I have seen a ton of beaver traces with lots of rather wacky/nonsensical work (at least from our rational point of view) ... never assumed that this might be the work of 'inexperienced' animals so far.

Comment: @fgysin My beaver knowledge and experience is getting rusty, but as I recall young beavers are ejected from the home and travel to find partners and new homes.  The rest is supposition. The image in the question is on a forest path.  The images in the answer has no wasted motion.  Assuming the question image is made by a beaver, it is not make by an adult building a dam.

Comment: Could also be that the beaver was feasting on the tree bark, as they do often. Mostly they go for the fresh young bark/branches/foliage near the top of the tree, but maybe this one was in the mood for something a bit... crunchier... :)

Comment: Beavers gnaw bark for food as the question photo indicates. The answer photo shows a tree felled for winter consumption, possibly underwater in a dam construction but not necessarily. Beavers use water to move branches more easily and safer (predators); most dam bark material will be consumed over winter.